# add dns txt record

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, domain

Whats the right way to type a txt dns record?

For example a txt verification required in that case:

Set a txt record on your domain that contains:

```
420ef575ed03afds3dcfbd22eafad9a4
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it largely depends on how you manage your DNS.  If it's BIND, here's the line that provides the TXT record for teaparty.net:

```
        IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a:spf.teaparty.net a:home.ddns.teaparty.net mx -all"
```

If you're a BIND user, I thought it might help to have a concrete example to work with; note that this line comes immediately after the SOA record, as it depends on position inside the file to pick up that it's a record for the domain itself, not some host or subdomain therein.

If you're not a BIND user, let us know what you **are** running.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your DNS management software but basically you just create new TXT record and put **420ef575ed03af13cdsbd22eafad9a4** in it.